# Can not update current Adapter within list View

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

Im trying to continue to add different files to add to my list view... I can add one file to my listView but when I select a different file to upload, it get rids of the old item and overwrites it with the new file... I want to keep adding to my list without getting rid of anything... I understand I need to update my current adapter but im confused how.

Here is what I have:

```
//update List

                        final  ArrayList<Uri>FileUpload = new ArrayList<Uri>();

                         final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,FileUpload);
                       //  adapter.add(uri.getPath());

                         lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListViewUpload);







                        //Upload to list button with selected file
                        Button uploadList = (Button) findViewById(R.id.UpdateList);
                        uploadList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListViewUpload);
                                lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                                adapter.add(uri.getPath());
                                ((BaseAdapter) lv.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();



                                Toast.makeText(dropBox.this, "File Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



                            }
                        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code, there's no need to set adapter every time you add an item. Try this:

```
Button uploadList = (Button) findViewById(R.id.UpdateList);
uploadList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        adapter.add(uri.getPath());
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        Toast.makeText(dropBox.this, "File Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: I think I may have to modify the rest of my code that is not shown here... I feel like I have the right components but theres something else that needs debugging